# Sending querystring variable to new popup window

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

My JavaScript code is this:

```
var newwindow;
    function poptastic(url) {
     newwindow = window.open(url, 'name', 'height=400,width=200');
    if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
    }
```

And my C# code:

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in GvComments.Rows)
            {
                Button btnReplay = (Button)row.FindControl("btnReplay");
                string url = "javascript:poptastic('Configuration.aspx?id=" + e.CommandArgument + "')";
                btnReplay.Attributes.Add("onclick", url);
            }
```

I think the C# code has problem, because when I use this JavaScript code in a tag it works, but in `attribute.add` not working.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:java] and not [tag:c#]?

Comment: I guess java script code has problem ..

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML?

Comment: No .. I can't see .. just it is doing post back operation

Comment: [tag:java] ***is not at all the same thing*** as [tag:javascript]

Comment: Along with Matt's comment.  It is NOT "java script", it is "javascript".  One word.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `OnClientClick` for this instead:

```
btnReplay.OnClientClick = String.Format("poptastic(\"Configuration.aspx?id={0}\");return false;", e.CommandArgument);
```

**EDIT**

Here's a JavaScript function you can use to open popup windows:

```
openChildWindowWithDimensions = function(url, width, height, showMenu, canResize, showScrollbars) {
    var childWindow = window.open(url, "", "\"width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",menubar=" + (showMenu ? "1" : "0") + ",scrollbars=" + (showScrollbars ? "1" : "0") + ",resizable=" + (canResize ? "1" : "0") + "\"");
    if (childWindow){
        childWindow.resizeTo(width, height);
        childWindow.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens exactly? Does it do anything? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, can you add a semicolon here: `newwindow.focus();`

Comment: @Persian: "not working" doesn't mean anything.  See James comment above.

Answer (score 0):

This problem would be very easy to answer, if you can provide the HTML generated. To find HTML generated go the browser window where you are seeing the rendered page and do a View Source. See [How do I check my site's source code](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=75129)

With the code you have provided all the suggestions I can make are already made by @James Johnson
Please see a minor correction to James code
    `btnReplay.OnClientClick = String.Format("poptastic('Configuration.aspx?id={0}');return false;", e.CommandArgument);`
Note: I have changed \" to '